# Google Apps Script search not returning all threads

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I'm trying to search threads under one label. This is the code I have for the search:

```
      //set "label" to label to be searched
  var label = "sampleLabel"

  //get all threads with the label 
  var emails = GmailApp.search('label: ' + label);
```

I tested it on a label with 11 threads (each with one message in it) and it only returned 3.

I saw this was asked before, but that seemed to be a different issue.

I appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: Please edit your question and include examples of your data what you are requesting and what you expect to see returned also test your searching in gmail to ensure that it works there.

Answer (score 0):

There is a actually an easy way to get all the threads with a specific label! [See the method documentation here.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getuserlabelbynamename)

```
var LABEL = "mylabel";

// Get out labels by name
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(LABEL);

// The threads currently assigned to the label
var threads = label.getThreads();
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still only returned the same three threads ignoring the other 8.

Comment: @niko Then you need to post more about what is and isn't returning because based on what you've posted I can only guess at what the issue it.